# How to export smart PDF form data to an excel format without images?

Tags: vba, csv, pdf

I have a very large amount of PDF forms (with the same format) that I want to export to a filterable excel file. These forms contain images embedded throughout. When exporting with adobe standard, the .csv file obtained includes massive amounts of random characters as the 'image data'. Since I have so many pdf forms I obviously do not want to include this. When importing the files into excel, it generates massive columns and rows of random characters due to the image data

I've been writing a bit in VBA to try and exclude the columns of nonsense, but my code is too specific and too slow. I want a more efficient way to do this.

```
Sub OpenCSV()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim FilePath As String, rownumber As Integer, j As Integer

'Select The File

FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Select CSV file")

Open FilePath For Input As #1

rownumber = 0

' Loop continues until End Of File

Do Until EOF(1)

Line Input #1, LineFromFile

'Make an array from the file

LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

j = 0
    For i = 0 To 314

' This If statement removes the images (only works if report is in exact same format)

If i <> 86 And i <> 87 And i <> 88 And i <> 89 Then

Cells(1, 1).Offset(rownumber, j).Value = LineItems(i)

j = j + 1

End If

Next i

rownumber = rownumber + 1
Loop

Close #1

End Sub
```

This runs slowly and usually results in an error if there is a missing form entry etc. I am open to improving this code, or abandoning it if there is some sort of software solution existing.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you can extract only the form information and not the images. See example here: https://github.com/pdftables/vba-pdftables-api/blob/master/pdftables.vba